# Using a big struct as parameter with std async causes bug

Tags: c++, asynchronous, struct

I have a big struct that needs to be processed. So I use std async to do it on another thread. Here is a simple example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

 
using namespace std;

struct teststruct{
    float thisvalue[32][32][64];
};

void foo(teststruct thisdummy) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(234));
    cout << "hello";
}

int main() {
    teststruct thisteststruct;
    foo(thisteststruct); // this does work
    auto futurevalue = async(launch::async, foo, thisteststruct); //this doesnt work

    return 0;
}
```

I have a struct that is just a big 3d array of floats. When I run this I get an error saying Bus error: 10. Just calling foo without using async works but using std async it doesn't work. Somehow it is related with the struct size since when I make the struct

```
struct teststruct{
        float thisvalue[32][32][63];
};
```

it magically works. I have tried splitting up the struct by half so a 32x32x32 array instead of a 32x32x64 array and taking in teststructs as parameters but it doesn't work. As I said above I think this has to do with the size of the struct. How can I fix this?

Comment: My guess is that the thread doesn't have enough memory allocated to it, ie. 256KB is the max for your system. A few extra data are stored for the thread so you can't use all 256KB.

Comment: Can't you just pass the address of that struct?

Comment: Does the `async()` force the main to wait until it completes? If not then `main()` can exit (and destroy `thisteststruct`) before the async method has a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably blowing the stack.

`sizeof(teststruct)` is `32*32*64*sizeof(float)`.  Assuming a 4-byte float, that's 256KB that you are attempting to pass by value into `foo`.

While there are flags you can pass to the compiler to increase stack size, you really want to avoid passing large objects by value.  As that requires an in-memory copy to be made.    Pass that big struct by shared_pointer. That will enable it to be passed around on the main thread and on the async thread without using any significant amount of stack memory. It's also faster since it avoids the large copy of that object.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <memory>

 
using namespace std;

struct teststruct{
    float thisvalue[32][32][64];
};


void foo(shared_ptr<teststruct> thisdummy) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(234));
    cout << "hello";
}

int main() {
    auto thisteststruct = make_shared<teststruct>();
    foo(thisteststruct);
    auto futurevalue = async(launch::async, foo, thisteststruct);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea but since the data will be modified while in the thread I would have to use a mutex, causing a bottleneck. But I found out that I didn't need to use all of the data only a portion which solves the issue. But never the less thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Making it a pointer or reference should do the trick.

(untested)

```cpp
void foo(teststruct *thisdummy) {
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(234));
    cout << "hello";
}

int main() {
    teststruct thisteststruct;
    foo(&thisteststruct); // this does work
    auto futurevalue = async(launch::async, foo, &thisteststruct); //this doesnt work

    futurevalue.get();

    return 0;
}
```

What the below discussion is about is:

> If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound
> to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the
> end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes,
> essentially making code such as the following synchronous:

See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async)

Comment: What happens when `main` returns and destructs `thisteststruct` while `foo` is running async in a different thread and presumably is still accessing that object.  :)

Comment: @selbie nearly the same as the OP's program does, it kills the thread and close the program.

Comment: You can't guarantee that the async function is cancelled and has returned before teststruct is deleted. In his particular case, his async function doesn't do anything, so no harm.  But the moment he changes it to access that pointer parameter, all bets are off.

Comment: @selbie While true, your answer doesn't address that either, so I don't know why you're complaining about it here...

Comment: What I'm saying it that it's not safe to pass a stack object by pointer to a function that runs in another thread.  The shared_ptr solution works well in this case.

Comment: @selbie You're wrong anyway; the declaration of `futurevalue` effectively blocks on completion of `foo` here

Comment: @selbie _"it's not safe to pass a stack object by pointer to a function that runs in another thread. The shared_ptr solution works well in this case"_ I fail to see the distinction? If `thisteststruct` were to go out of scope, doesn't really matter what it is; any access to it is invalid.

Comment: @selbie Oh, I see, you were imagining that it would be safe because there's a reference still standing. If you let a thread live until the end of the program without joining it, _all bets are off_. But (per above) that's not the case here anyway.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings - Most of my day is spent reviewing pull requests involving multiple threads.

Comment: Mostly there: make it `foo(&thisteststruct);`

Comment: @selbie Then you might want to read up about the behaviour of `std::async` and `std::future` before doing that again. I've given you a head start above.